# how do I lookup server and web host information of popular web sites?

Tags: web-hosting

I'm looking to host my own website, and was searching for good hosts - Linux based servers with PHP support. While checking up on popular webhosts, this question struck.

Is there a way to find the server details - statistics like web host name, OS used, version etc.. -  of any website that you want? For example, if I want to look up on the host/ server details of say google.com, what has to be done? Any online options?

Comment: try builtwith.com, you should note thought that large sites will ether use their own datacenters, or use enterprise hosting/co-location (Generally not cost effective unless you have 200 servers)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, [Netcraft](http://news.netcraft.com/) gathers this information

Answer (score 0):

Without thinking too much, OS could be found in headers or requesting a non-existant page (404). Although good web pages will have custom error pages, some may show the web server version.

You could also try with a whois on the domain to search the domain registrar. Could not be the same as the hosting but trying is cheap.